# Why is the text-align property not working inside a button element?

Tags: html, css, button, text-align

```
button {
    text-align: center;
    font-size:50px;
    color:black;
    border:2px solid white;
    border-style:dotted;
    border-color:red;
}
```

When i run this code, all the properties work except the text-align. I don't understand why is the text-align not working when it's inside a button?

Note: Yes, i know there are ways to align the button in the center, i am not asking how to align the button, i am asking why is the text-align not working inside the button element like all the other properties are working?

Comment: Your code is working, please see if other css is overriding your css

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the rendered button showing the issue and/or add a snippet?

Comment: Hi, i posted the full code and the screenshot below.

Comment: The text inside the button is indeed horizontally centered. Increase the width of the button to see. Change the line-height if you're referring to vertical centering.

Comment: The text-align property applies to the horizontal placement of the text within the button, not the alignment of the button itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work like this. Assigning the `text-align:center` property to the button itself won't align it to center. You should assign this property to its parent. or you can assign width to the button and add `margin: 0 auto;` as alternative way.

Here is the solution for your issue.
Add this CSS

```
.btnwrap {
  text-align: center;
}
```

And, wrap your button with `<p>`

```
<p class="btnwrap">
  <button>button 2</button>
</p>
```

Comment: Please check the `Note` of questioner which says `i am not asking how to align the button, i am asking why is the text-align not working`

Comment: that is what i included in my answer. its the reason why he is having the issue and also added alternative solution to it.

Comment: hi, i've posted a screenshot of the code and the output below, could you check it out and tell me what i am doing wrong? What is the 'parent' of the button? I tried adding margin 0 but still not working.

Comment: Checked your screenshot and your code too. a 'parent' is an html element which wraps its child element. as i already mentioned, assigning `text-align:center` to the button itself won't work, you need to put the button inside some other element for example `<p>` and assign `text-align:center` to it. I have included solution in my edited answer, check it out.

Comment: Thanks for the center. Yes, i know putting the button inside p or h1 parent will make it move in the center, but what i could not understand is, why do i have to put it inside a parent, why the text align doesn't work if its inside the button code? 

Is it because the code i assign within the button applies for the button, and therefore assigning text align will be applied to the text WITHIN the button itself, and moving the button requires moving the place on which the button is located? Does that make sense? 

I haven't learned class yet, i am still learning and experimenting with html.

Comment: I am guessing it would be more easy to move the button if i use css instead of internal css within the html, if i just categorize the button in a div and then use text align in the css file? Am i correct? Why is it not working in the html alone?

Comment: I guess you didn't really understand what I tried to explain. Try going through this link https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-align/

Answer (score 0):

try to add margin auto

```
text-align: center;
margin: auto;
```

or give `!important` to `text-align` maybe there's another css code effecting  ur button

Comment: I tried margin : auto but still not working. I've posted the ss of the code above, could you check it out and tell me what im doing wrong?

Comment: it's working well what is the problem ?? i think you want to center the button not the text itself because the text already centered